# How to install Python, VSCode, and flake8 correctly on Win10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, visual-studio-code, flake8

I greatly apologize for the newbie question. I am trying to correctly download and integrate a Python 3.7 installation with VSCode and using flake8 as a linter. I want to get set up for developing custom scripts for Blender. I'm on Win10 x64.

1. I downloaded the "python-3.7.8-amd64.exe" installation package, and installed it.
2. I made sure to select the checkbox that adds python to the PATH environment variable in the installer.
3. I pointed VSCode to the newly installed interpreter and was then prompted to install a linter.
4. Someone recommended flake8, so I selected that in VSCode and installed.
5. During the installation I get the following warnings:

`WARNING: The script pyflakes.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\futur\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.`

`WARNING: The script pycodestyle.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\futur\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.       Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.`

`WARNING: The script flake8.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\futur\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH. Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.`

`Successfully installed flake8-3.8.3 importlib-metadata-1.7.0 mccabe-0.6.1 pycodestyle-2.6.0 pyflakes-2.2.0 zipp-3.1.0`

I checked my environment variables and this is what shows up:

[image: PATH Variables]

What I don't understand is why I have two Python directories in %APPDATA%. There is:

`C:\Users\futur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts`

As well as:

`C:\Users\futur\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts`

flake8 installed in the Roaming folder, while my main Python installation is in

`C:\Users\futur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37`

So to conclude, these are my questions:

1. Did flake8 install in the wrong directory?
2. Should I add `C:\Users\futur\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts` to my USER PATH environment variable, or to my SYSTEM PATH environment variable?
3. Why are there two Python directories in %appdata%? (Roaming and Local)

Any guidance on how to properly set everything up correctly would be an ENORMOUS help and greatly appreciated.

### Edit 1

Thank so much for all the answers. I want to emphasize that I would prefer to get this issue sorted out without just installing Anaconda.

### Edit 2

I made some progress here. Instead of installing flake8 through VSCode, I just ran `python -m pip install flake8` and everything seems good now.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I successfully installed flake8.

I think there is a problem with your installation path of flake8.

Its default path will not be in roaming.
The default path will only have: C:\Users\futur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts    and C:\Users\futur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37；

The default is local, which usually stores executable programs and other large capacity files;

It is recommended that you could install python again and check the version and location of the pip (use "pip -- version").

Comment: That's what I suspected. I'm going to give this a try when I get to my office in a little bit. Thing is, I don't know how to change the install path of flake8. VSCode doesn't give me the option.

Comment: It is recommended that you could install python again. By default, flake8 will be installed in local. In addition, you could use cmd to install it(use"pip install flake8").

Answer (score 0):

You could use an environment tool to resolve all these.

Download [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) and create a environment with your intended python version and install flake8 inside your conda env. VScode works well with anaconda env.

Comment: XPost from another answer: Does Anaconda support older versions of Python? I need 3.7.8 for compatibility with Blender. Looking at the website it appears Anaconda is geared towards data science and machine learning, I just want to write Blender addons. What is the difference between a vanilla python install and Anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

Download Anaconda it will auto-resolve all the problems which you are facing related to environment setup.

Comment: Does Anaconda support older versions of Python? I need 3.7.8 for compatibility with Blender. Looking at the website it appears Anaconda is geared towards data science and machine learning, I just want to write Blender addons. What is the difference between a vanilla python install and Anaconda?

Comment: Anaconda provide you all necessary packages n all and vanilla python install will provide basic setup to run a python script. for basic scripting, i will suggest go for vanilla python and integrate them to vscode.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think it is wrong. My new modules are also installed at same directory as yours.
2. For me, it only works when I add to SYSTEM PATH.
3. I also have Python in both Roaming and Local. But after checking my folders, it seem Local one is from my previous installation of Python.

As a side note, I also have to add env path for Python after installing Python installer. But, I remember clearly that in previous Python installers, I didn't have to add path manually. I wonder if there is any changes regarding path in new Python installer.

Comment: Maybe the Python directory changed from 3.7.8 to 3.8.X from Local to Roaming? I have no idea. In the installer there is a checkbox that adds Python to PATH, but it appears this option added the respective paths to USER PATH and not SYSTEM. Anyway, to clarify - your latest version of Python is in %appdata%/roaming?

Comment: Yup. My latest Python is 3.7 and it is in Roaming folder.

Answer (score 0):

What I think happened is you used a global install of Python to install flake8 and the Python extension does a user install to help prevent you from breaking your Python installation (`python -m pip install -u`). So one path is to Python itself and the other is your user install of packages for a specific version of Python. That's why there's two separate locations.

The best way to manage this is to create a virtual environment and install into that (you don't need to switch to conda for isolation). That global install you did using `python -m pip install flake8` is a bit risky as that could clash with other things you install in the future.